# What happened to the other dog?

Tags: plot-explanation, a-single-man

In [*A Single Man*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1315981/), according to Jim's cousin, Jim only had one dog with him when he died.

According to George's memories, they had two dogs. Since George asks about the dog, it means Jim had taken both dogs to his trip.

What happened to the other, female dog?